# Night-watch.js installation error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, nightwatch.js

trying to install night-watch to play around with it to test it against other frameworks, however, I am getting an error on install which I have no idea what it means. I have followed instructions on night-watch website but still receive an error:

$ npm install nightwatch

[image]

How do I solve this? installing on windows.

http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#installation

Comment: `npm init` your "project" and then install packages? I assumed you didn't do that before using `npm install`.

Comment: I guess I didin't were Can I get the information or guide were I missed that? @Nonemoticoner

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/ @Speedychuck -- make sure to create a directory for your project, then run npm init in the directory to create a package.json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I said in the comment, you have type `npm init` before you will start installing packages with `npm install [package_name]`. Here's more info:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init

Also, keep in mind you can't *name* your package in package.json file as packages you're going to install within or it will fail to install one.